# How to check why my static IP isn't working?

Tags: webserver, static-ip

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop edition.  I'm not overly familiar with the unix side, but I'm learning.

From a fresh install, I basically only installed XAMPP.  My webserver now works fine (although with dynamic IP).

I'm at a university, so the IT office gave me a static IP and all the accompanying info to set it up.

My subdomain with the university works (although, IP dynamic)

In an attempt to apply static IP, I then modified my `/etc/network/interfaces` file to the effect of:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

This killed my network connection: I can't even ping the computer (or ping any other systems from the computer).  It seems pretty straightforward, but something obviously went wrong.  I'm not sure where to even begin debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, then it is running its own network manager (conveniently called `NetworkManager`) and will override the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. You either need to setup static ip's through NetworkManager, or [disable it](http://dijks.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/how-to-disable-network-manager-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise/).

Comment: So I setup the static IP in networkmanager.  This worked: I can now access the computer at the static IP.  However, I am no longer able to access it at the domain name for some reason?  I have entries for in /etc/hosts for:  127.0.1.1 computername.

Comment: do you mean 127.0.0.1 (assuming the 1.1 is a typo)? Also did you revert the `/etc/network/interfaces` file back to just the loopback interface?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use static ip address, make sure removing dhcp client

```
sudo apt-get remove dhcp-client
```

And then use only

```
auto lo eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Specify your name server(DNS servers) under `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

and put e.g

```
name server 8.8.8.8
```

After doing all this, make sure restarting your network by:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```